# Legend Items: No Symbols

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, legend, layouts

I am working on exporting my maps through the layout editor, but in the generated legend the symbols are not appearing as they should. As you can see from the screenshot, the "Legend Items" displays everything I want it to display, but on the map itself, the circles are missing.

[image]

Comment: You can try unchecking "Resize to fit contents".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the symbolization for the legend of the layout in QGIS main window. Either Go to `Layer styling panel` or `Layer properties / Tab Symbology`. In both cases, on the bottom, click `Advanced` and select `Data-defined size legend…`. Than you can choose e.g. `Collapsed legend` as shown in the screenshot below.

For details [see the documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html?highlight=layer#data-defined-size-legend).

*Settings in QGIS main window / Layer properties:*
[image]

*See the result in the layout editor:*

[image]

Comment: This is great and the symbols came up! The only problem is that they are extremely small in my legend, much smaller than on my map. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot, showing the exact same menus etc. as my screenshot? You can edit your original question, paste the screenshot there, than copy the link introduced at the bottom of the edit field (semthing like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/.... ) and than post this link here in a comment.

Comment: Never mind, I just fixed it, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Great, you're welcome!